# asp.net ajax problems running on IE8

Tags: asp.net, ajax

When I run my site on IE8, I encountered quite a lot of errors:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8)
Timestamp: Fri, 2 Mar 2012 08:14:49 UTC


Message: Invalid character
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://domain.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=O7JwLqZOIoHNlyCkNvK03tVvwuzvkYzynDHEqBGR30nqirqFAfsC6VLnIXSHI0l3rFJe5scxTspJ0gL8j7be7Z_M_qupspyObc8e_qKqmjxQl4OjmnXPOHJT-RM3vez242U9hA2&t=ffffffffdf30da43


Message: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.
Line: 73
Char: 34
Code: 0
URI: http://domain.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fdefault.aspx


Message: Invalid character
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://domain.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=x-PyXQzFvir2kqZvMkDldfow6niFV3KYY__01Nn2zVQMASkFkW-fZS-09Ipt80ps5_kADl0sK9a-yZA5TAOtuvFVl7jFFb-4YTeAP5BxnpFSDyXvJxekdRPmR1GX1UDorkCAP1AxvEsvFwT2_NPk5CK0f5E1&t=ffffffffdf30da43


Message: 'Sys' is undefined
Line: 84
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://domain.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fdefault.aspx


Message: 'Sys' is undefined
Line: 192
Char: 122
Code: 0
URI: http://domain.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fdefault.aspx


Message: 'Sys' is undefined
Line: 3
Char: 347
Code: 0
URI: http://domain.com/login.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d3.5.50927.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-US%3a4a126967-c4d4-4d5c-8f94-b4e3e72d7549%3ade1feab2%3af2c8e708%3a8613aea7%3af9cec9bc%3a3202a5a2%3aa67c2700%3a720a52bf%3a589eaa30%3aab09e3fe%3a87104b7c%3abe6fb298


Message: 'Sys' is undefined
Line: 198
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://domain.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fdefault.aspx
```

How to fix those with my asp.net 3.5 and Ajax supported?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be due to this bug - http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/26843

Comment: no, it is not similar to that bug I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because I have both .NET 4.0 and .NET 3.5 on my IIS server. If I removed .NET 4.0, the problem is gone.